# Update the rotation of a CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am trying to update the current rotation (and sometimes the position) of a CALayer.

What I am trying to in a couple of simple steps:

1. Store a couple of `CALayers` in an array, so I can reuse them
2. Set the anchor point of all CALayers to 0,0.
3. Draw `CALayer` objects where the object starts at a position on a circle
4. The layers are rotated by the same angle as the circle at that position
5. Update the position and rotation of the CALayer to match new values

Here is a piece of code I have:

`lineWidth` is the width of a line
`self.items` is an array containing the `CALayer` objects

```
func updateLines() {

    var space = 2 * M_PI * Double(circleRadius);
    var spaceAvailable = space / (lineWidth)

    var visibleItems = [Int]();

    var startIndex = items.count - Int(spaceAvailable);
    if (startIndex < 0) {
        startIndex = 0;
    }

    for (var i = startIndex; i < self.items.count; i++) {
        visibleItems.append(self.items[i]);
    }

    var circleCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    /* Each line should move up and rotate accordin to this value */
    var anglePerLine: CGFloat = (360 / CGFloat(visibleItems.count)).toRadians()

    /* Starting position, 270 degrees is on top */
    var startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(270).toRadians();

    /* Lines default rotation, we rotate it to get the right side up */
    var lineAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(180).toRadians();

    for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < visibleItems.count; itemIndex++) {
        var itemLayer = self.itemLayers[itemIndex];
        itemLayer.opacity = 1 - ((0.9 / visibleItems.count) * itemIndex);

        /* Calculate start position of layer */
        var x = CGFloat(circleRadius) * cos(startAngle) + CGFloat(circleCenter.x);
        var y = CGFloat(circleRadius) * sin(startAngle) + CGFloat(circleCenter.y);
        var height = CGFloat((arc4random() % 80) + 10);

        /* Set position and frame of layer */
        itemLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y), CGFloat(lineWidth), height);
        itemLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y));

        var currentRotation = CGFloat((itemLayer.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z") as NSNumber).floatValue);
        var newRotation = lineAngle - currentRotation;

        var rotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(itemLayer.transform, CGFloat(newRotation), 0, 0, 1);
        itemLayer.transform = rotationTransform;

        lineAngle += anglePerLine;
        startAngle += anglePerLine;
    }
}
```

The result of the first  run is exactly as I want it to be:

[image]

The second run through this code just doesn't update the CALayers correctly and it starts to look like this:

[image]

I think it has to do with my code to update the `location` and `transform` properties of the CALayer, but whatever I do, it always results in the last picture.

Comment: Ahhh!! Great stuff done by you. A silly suggestion - You could use images and animate them to looks like spinning.

Comment: It's actually a graph, with random length lines. And I want to reuse the CALayers I already have in there to be able to animate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered via Twitter: setting frames and transform is mutually exclusive. Happy to help. Finding my login credentials for SO is harder. :D

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer thanks to @iosengineer on Twitter. When setting a `position` on the CALayer, you do not want to update the `frame` of the layer, but you want to update the `bounds`.

[Smooth animation FTW](http://sortedbits.com/Chart.mov)

Comment: LOL. Looks like something spiky that I wouldn't want to hold.